# Inserting JSON into HTML via script tag - is this safe?

Tags: json, node.js, express

Using express framework -

I am loading an initial JSON state representation into my template that my react front end will rehydrate its initial state from, but I'm wondering if it is safe to do something like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.INIT_DATA = <%- initialState %>
</script>
```

The output of that if I view the page source might look something like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.INIT_DATA = {"recentImages": [ 11342, 11344, 11432 ], "lastOnline": "Yesterday"}
</script>
```

Is this safe to do?  Are there any good practices to follow?  Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are going to update state and you will query it from the server anyway. So why don't you query initial state the same way?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not safe. Suppose the `initialState` contains a string that looks like this:

```
"hello! </script><script>alert("PWND")</script>"
```

This will cause the embedded code to run. In other words: if the JSON you're embedding contains any user supplied strings you're opening the door to XSS attacks.

To prevent this, replace `</` with `<\/`, and `<!--` with `<\!--`. In JSON strings `\/` and `\!` will be interpreted as a simple slash or exclamation mark, so this doesn't change the semantics of the JSON, but it will prevent the HTML parser from seeing a closing tag.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see why this wouldn't be safe? However I suggest you don't store the variable in the window object; it is discouraged as the window is a global object.